# Click the button using playwright

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, nodelist, playwright-python

I have a problem with playwright using python for automation, when I manipulate a button on the website, i had a problem, because it gives me an error, first I will show the code in Python

```py
button = page.locator("button.p-ripple").first()
button.click()
```

In this case, I want to press this button, it is inside a p button, apparently an element used in Angular. I'm calling this method inside the function I created that has page as a parameter, and in this case I use the function inside main

This is the result when selecting the element from the DOM

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button.p-ripple")
result -> NodeList [ button.p-button.p-component.p-ripple ]
```

This is the result right after placing the indexing, it finds the element

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button.p-ripple")[0]
result -> <button class="p-button p-component p-ripple" pripple="" type="button">
```

I wanted to do the same with playwright using python, but neither first() nor nth(index) work for me, this error appears

**'Locator' object is not callable
File "/file.py", line 84, in function_python
button = page.locator("button.p-ripple").first()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/file.py", line 133, in main
function_python(page)
File "/file.py", line 140, in 
main()
TypeError: 'Locator' object is not callable**

(on line 84 is where the locator is, on line 133 is where the function I created within the main function is located, its function is to call the browser page, on line 140 is the main function that I call in the initializer)

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def main():
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        firefox = playwright.firefox
        browser = firefox.launch(headless=False)
        context = browser.new_context()
        timeout = 60000
        
        page = context.new_page()
        page.set_default_navigation_timeout(timeout)
        page.set_default_timeout(timeout)
        
        login(page)
        function_python(page)
        browser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Where do I instantiate page and initialize main

This is element

```html
<lib-pesquisa _nghost-hbk-c66=""><div _ngcontent-hbk-c66="" class="p-d-flex p-12 p-mb-3"><button _ngcontent-hbk-c66="" icon="pi pi-plus" label="Button1" pbutton="" type="button" class="p-button-success p-button p-component"><span class="p-button-icon p-button-icon-left pi pi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="p-button-label">Button1</span></button><p-button _ngcontent-hbk-c66="" icon="pi pi-search" label="Button2" class="p-ml-3"><button pripple="" type="button" class="p-button p-component p-ripple"><!----><span class="pi pi-search p-button-icon p-button-icon-left ng-star-inserted" aria-hidden="true"></span><!----><span class="p-button-label" aria-hidden="false">Button2</span><!----></button></p-button></div><p-dialog _ngcontent-hbk-c66="" header="Button2" class="ng-tns-c62-1"><!----></p-dialog></lib-pesquisa>
```

Button I want to click

```html
<button pripple="" type="button" class="p-button p-component p-ripple"><!----><span class="pi pi-search p-button-icon p-button-icon-left ng-star-inserted" aria-hidden="true"></span><!----><span class="p-button-label" aria-hidden="false">Button2</span><!----></button>
```

Comment: Can you share how you get the `page` instance?

Comment: @hardkoded

Oh yes, I'm sorry, I added more information to the post

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem with the code, and I don't think it reproduces the "not callable" error stated, which requires something like `page.locator("foo")()`. Can you share a [mcve] with all methods defined and the page you're manipulating, or a reproduction of it? If you just have one element, `.first()` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @ggorlen

From what I understand, is that when I call the DOM element, it gives me a nodelist, passing a [0] it returns the button, however the playwright is used .firts(), but I don't know why this happens problem and I can't reproduce it's confidential, but thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] the post to clarify the use case fully. There should be runnable code. If the site is confidential, try to make a reproduction of the relevant behavior--otherwise, it's basically guesswork, which is probably going to be a poor experience for all involved. Thanks. DOM elements can't be called. Like I said, when there is a single element, `locator(selector).click()` should work. Actually, in Python, it's `page.locator("foo").first.click()` rather than `pge.locator("foo").first().click()`, but that shouldn't be necessary since `.first` is discouraged.

Comment: I can't guarantee that that fix will solve your scraping problem, but it'll at least solve the TypeError.

Comment: @ggorlen Okay, I'll try to replace

Comment: @ggorlen It didn't work, he just didn't press the button :(

Comment: Any errors? If not, you could try an untrusted click: `page.locator(selector).evaluate("el => el.click()")`. If that doesn't work, I'd have to see the site to say what the problem might be--there are a number of things that can explain why it won't click, ranging from timing/async behavior, to the server blocking or restricting your bot, to iframes/shadow DOM roots, to selecting the wrong element, to visibility....